# JavaScript scroll to anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having some problems with JavaScript / jQuery.

We're currently using a "shortcode" from Visual Composer (WordPress plugin) that creates (horizontal) tabs. We'we made some custom changes, but only visually (images/css).

We're trying to make it so that when you click on a tab you automatically scroll down to the content.

I've tried wrapping the script in

```
jQuery(document).ready( function({});
jQuery(window).ready( function({});
```

and also tried replacing **.ready()** with **.load()**

```
jQuery(".pws_tabs_controlls_item").children().click(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: jQuery(".ts-fancy-tabs-container").offset().top
    }, 700, 'swing', function () {});
});
```

However! If you copy the entire script and paste it in the **Console** in Chrome/Firefox it will work as intended, based on that I'd say that the script it self works, it feels like it's not loading or registering or w/e.

Is there any (obvious) problem/mistake we've made?

I'd be happy to provide additional information if neccessary (e.g. the website address)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no `ready` event for `window`. Also, are the children of `.pws_tabs_controlls_item` in the DOM when it's loaded, or are they injected via JavaScript?

Comment: Ya, sounds like you are trying to handle some dynamic elements. In this case, [delegate](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) event

Comment: Did you forget a closing parenthesis after the ready function or is it a just a typo in your post?

Comment: Yeah the tabs are loaded with javascript after page load, so yeah, probably dynamic elements.

Answer (score 3):

The VisualComposer plugin renders only after the `document` is ready, and that's why it's not working.

The best way to solve your problem is by using [jQuery's event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), e.g:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.pws_tabs_controlls_item > a', function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: jQuery(".ts-fancy-tabs-container").offset().top
    }, 700, 'swing', function () {});
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

After your comment, I can see that the anchor tags inside your `.pws_tabs_controlls_item` elements already have a `click` event listener, and it also uses `event.stopPropagation()`, so my code above will never be executed.

The other way to solve your problem, is by *dirty-checking* when the element is available, e.g:

```
function waitForAvailability(selector, callback) {
  if (jQuery('selector').length === 0) {
    callback();
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      waitForAvailability(selector, callback);
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

And then, you can use the code you were already using, something like that:

```
waitForAvailability('.pws_tabs_controlls_item', function() {
  jQuery(".pws_tabs_controlls_item").children().click(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: jQuery(".ts-fancy-tabs-container").offset().top
    }, 700, 'swing', function () {});
  });
});
```

Comment: Just wondering, isn't `.pws_tabs_controlls_item` static so we could delegate at its level? (even it doesn't really matter i guess)

Comment: It would be quicker to delegate the event to `.pws_tabs_controlls_item`. No point bubbling all the way up to `document` if it is static

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm not sure, but it seems that it's created by VisualComposer dynamically. In fact, while we have lack of information, I tried to give an answer that will actually work for the OP.

Comment: @Andy yeah, I agree with you. In fact, firstly I typed `jQuery('.pws_tabs_controlls_item').on('click', 'a', function() {`, but I thought it could be wrong if those items are being created dynamically.

Comment: @Buzinas You are completly right of course regarding posting an universal working answer. I posted previous comment because i was thinking you know exactly this plugin, that's why i was wondering :)

Comment: @A.Wolff in fact, I helped a friend in his Wordpress site with that plugin once, and I remember that it lazily loads a bunch of stuff (it was a nightmare), and that's why I answered in that way :)

Comment: Tried your solution, but it didn't work. 
The site in question is http://tylhammarscatering.universe.adwisemedia.se/catering-meny/ , hope it helps, i think the plugin creates the tabs dynamically and aren't static elements.

Comment: That's happening because your `a` tags already have an event listener, and it does `event.stopPropagation()`, so the code I put here will never be executed. I'll update my answer to something that will work for you :)

Comment: Was just about to leave the office, won't have time to look at it right now, but will check it out when i get home! @Buzinas

Comment: @Buzinas Hello! sorry for taking so long! We'vetried out the new script that you made and It's basically the same as before, only work if you paste it into the browser console.